# Order by money amount in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, currency

I'm having Products with embedded Listings.

As a result, I would like to have a list ordered on price. I'm using mongoid & Money gem. However, I later add newly created listings (from external apis), so ordering via mongoid doesnt make sense.

Listing contains :price. Price is a Money type, containing :cents & :currency.

listing.rb:

```
scope :order_on_price, order_by("price.cents" => "desc")
```

this doesnt work either:

```
  scope :order_on_price, sort_by{ |price| price[:cents]}
```

products_controller.rb (after external apis are loaded in):

```
@product.listings = @product.listings.order_on_price
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks..

**UPDATE:**

Added console output:

```
1.9.3-p327 :005 > Product.last.listings
 => [#<Listing _id: 514374bc98d12b3a3f00a164, created_at: 2013-03-15 19:21:32 UTC, updated_at: 2013-03-15 19:21:32 UTC, price: {"cents"=>3755, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}, availability: true, scan_id: "513f4cdf3e15fce2eaec43b6">]
```

Comment: If you are trying to order based on all listings then you need to have listings as separate documents using `belongs_to`

Comment: no, not based on all listing. purely the ones that are in Product.

Comment: can you post the rails console output of @product.listings?

Comment: @beck03076, its included!

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the listings in order I would do something like this:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  reordered_listings = product.listings.order_on_price
  product.listings.clear
  reordered_items.each { |i| product.listings.create i.attributes }
end
```

This is going to get in the wrong order every time you enter a new listing, so I would probably just sort the listings each time you retrieve a product.

Answer (score 0):

On the Listing class, define a <=> method.

```
def <=>(other)
  other.price <=> price
end
```

Now you can just reference the listings like this:

```
product.listings.sort
```

Or define a method, listings_by_price:

```
def listings_by_price
  listings.sort
end
```

Comment: thanks @tdahlke, however: it gives this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Money fractional:39899 currency:EUR>
(my apologies btw, i also changed cents -> fractional)